# 2D transformation without rotation

Tags: terminology, transformation, rotations

Is there a name for 2D transformation with the least squares adjustment having the following parameters:

shift_x,
shift_y,
scale.

Transformation does not use any rotation... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean an affine transformation? All transformations of the form you've mentioned are affine, though affine transformations can include rotations too.

Comment: I'm not aware of any exact term; I would just call it a composition of a translation and a scaling. Although if you consider "affine transformation", then "similarity transformation" would be more specific as it rules out shearing.

Comment: I wonder, if this transformation has the exact name (like Helmert...). It belongs to the group of affine transformations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Homothety, or homothetic transformation

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothety

Comment: Thanks... And greetings to Israel, just I am reading a book from Amos Oz :-).